# FormKey validation in Custom Form for Contacts

Tags: magento-1.9.3.9

I have a custom form setup for my contacts module. I would like to implement a form key to prevent spam. Usually, the spammer directly uses the form post without having a session before. So form key seems to be a solution. But. I am having some problems implementing this.

This is my custom form in index.phtml where I have already added the hidden input "FormKey" before closing the form-tag:

```
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
            <div class="fieldset">
                <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
                <ul class="form-list">
                    <li class="fields">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone')) ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />

                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="wide">
                        <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>

                        <div class="input-box">
                            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('dsgvo')->toHtml(); ?> 
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
        </form>
```

This is my Controller in IndexController.php

```
 <?php
require_once "Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php";  

class Centerfy_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'contacts/email/email_template';
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED          = 'contacts/contacts/enabled';

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if( !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED) ) {
            $this->norouteAction();
        }
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
        ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post', array('_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure())) );

        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>             


                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->setTemplateSubject(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Form'))
                ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

}
```

How do I setup my controller to check the formkey against the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Pass encrypted string in your `.phtml` file like this

```
<input name="form_key_hidden" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey().'259a8240fba23e82626efdc9eaa0c483';?>" />
```

Add condition in the start of code in `postAction()`

```
$customformKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key_hidden');
// $customformKey = $this->getRequest()->getPost('form_key');// try this if getParam() is null
if ($customformKey == Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey().'259a8240fba23e82626efdc9eaa0c483') {
   // Your code
}
```

As an alternate Solution, You can add

1. Google CAPTCHA
2. Block the IP address

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I implemented that today an I will see if it works or not. Is there a way to test ist?

Comment: @MariusHar `if condition` is matched then you can implement your code, you can test it by simply `echoing` in `if condition` to see if it works or not.

Comment: The Variable $FormKey you used throws a null reference because I didnt define it. How did you define it and where?

Comment: that's my bad, please check my updated answer.

Comment: nope null reference still there
[Thu Jul 18 14:06:05 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFormKey() on null in /home/host/Arbeit/DEV/mikroskopcenter/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/centerfy_contacts/index.phtml:54
Stack trace:
#0 /home/host/Arbeit/DEV/mikroskopcenter/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include()
#1 /home/host/Arbeit/DEV/mikroskopcenter/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')

Comment: I flushed the cache; formkey validation is on; deleted session_cache

Comment: okay, is it working now?

Comment: no, null reference ist still there. See my comment before. Do i have to include the some extended Framework for "getFormKey"?

Comment: can you try this way `Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend')->getFormKey());`

Comment: doesn't change anything. also null reference.

Comment: [Thu Jul 18 14:39:40 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFormKey() on null in /home/host/Arbeit/DEV/mikroskopcenter/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/centerfy_contacts/index.phtml:54

Comment: can you try this way `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`

Comment: Same Error which makes me confused. I think the error is cached somewhere, somehow. Because if this statement would fail there must be an error with "getBlockHtml('formkey')" but its still "getFormKey()".

Comment: try after `cache:flush` and try in private window

Comment: no, error still there after
./vendor/n98/magerun/bin/n98-magerun cache:flush
Cache cleared
an Private Window in Firefox. Also tried Internet Explorer but its the same. ahhhhhhhhhh! :D

Comment: It works! Thanks Mohit Rane. Had a second index.phtml to edit. It was just one of these dumb things. Made my Day

Comment: glad i could help.

Comment: Thanks. You can upvote answer if it's helpful for you. So, other developer can use this answer

Comment: I tried to upvote but my reputation is too low :( but i did the checkmark

Comment: that's okay, no problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to add below code at postAction() method before running of rest of code f this method/function.

```
public function postAction()
{
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
            return;
        }
    //Rest of code of  postAction()

}
```